# Integrals involving Hermite Polynomials

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, quantum-mechanics

Could you please tell me, How to evaluate this integral which involve hermite polynomials, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}x^{2q}H_m(x)H_n(x)\,dx=?$ where $H_n$ is the $n$-th Hermite polynomial (Physicist's version) and $q,\,m$ and $n$ are positive integers.
If $x^{2q}$ term were absent, I am able to perform the integral by writing the product of the Hermite polynomials into a single Hermite polynomial with a higher degree.
Can anybody give me a hint to perform this integral?

Comment: But $y^{2q}$ (and $e^{-ay^2}$) is independent of $x$...

Comment: sorry man, Now it is corrected in terms of x

Comment: @svyatoslav - maybe your method of fourier transform will work here?  My computation using hermite identities is proving to be a challenge.

Comment: @Tom Davis, thank you, I also think that FT could be used here. In fact we just have to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}H_m(x)H_n(x)\,dx$ - the initial integral is q's derivative with respect to parameter $a$. I will try :)

Comment: aha, i can do this integral as well...  good insight.

Comment: @Tom Davis I'm afraid there is no way to get a simple expression. For $I(n,m)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}H_m(x)H_n(x)\,dx$, using $H_n(x)=\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\exp(-t^2+2tx)|_{t=0}$ I got $I(n,m)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\frac{d^m}{dp^m} \exp\Bigl((1/a-1)(t^2+p^2)+\frac{2pt}{a}\Bigr)|_{t=p=0}$. More closed expression is given by Gradshteyn&Ryzhik 7.374 (5): $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2a^2x^2}H_m(x)H_n(x)\,dx=Const\,\, a^{(-n-m-1)}(1-2a^2)^{(m+n)/2}$$*_2F_1\Bigl(-m,n;\frac{1-n-m}{2};\frac{a^2}{2a^2-1}\Bigr)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you know how to do it when the $x^{2q}$ term is missing.  But the following website explains the effect of multiplying a Hermite polynomial by $x$, and you could just apply this rule $2q$ times.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Recursion_relation_2

I know you will end up with a bit of a mess.  But at least this should work to give concrete formulae in the case that $q$ is small.

Comment: Thanks man, that will work. But it will be a series solution, anyway thanks for the hint. Warm welcome to similar and other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the solution for arbitrary $q$
$$
I_{nm}(q)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}x^{2q}H_n(x)H_m(x)dx
$$
are the derivatives of the integral
$$
I_{nm}(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}H_n(x)H_m(x)dx
$$
with respect to $a$
$$
I_{nm}(q)=(-1)^q\frac{\partial^q}{\partial a^q}I_{nm}(0).
$$

The $q=0$ integral can be done by linearization and scaling.  First, transform to the probabilists Hermite polynomials and use linearization to obtain
$$
I_{nm}(0) = 2^{\frac{n+m}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\operatorname{min}(n,m)}{n\choose k}{m\choose k}k!\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ay^2}He_{n+m-2k}(\sqrt{2}y)dy.
$$
Now change the integration variable to get the probabilists weighting function $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{a}y$ leading to
$$
I_{nm}(0) = 2^{\frac{n+m-1}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\sum_{k=0}^{\operatorname{min}(n,m)}{n\choose k}{m\choose k}k!\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}He_{n+m-2k}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a}}\right)dy.
$$
Now use the scaling formula
$$
\operatorname{He}_{n+m-2k}(\gamma x) =(n+m-2k)!\sum_{s=0}^{\frac{n+m}{2}-k}\frac{1}{2^ss!(n-m-2k-2s)!}\gamma^{n-m-2k-2s}\left(\gamma^2-1\right)^s \operatorname{He}_{n-m-2k-2s}(x),
$$
the floor function on the upper limit of the sum is not necessary since this integral is zero if $n$ and $m$ have opposite parity.  Therefore the sum is always even.  Also, since this sum is integrated, only the maximum $s$ term is retained by orthogonality.  Therefore the integral becomes
$$
I_{nm}(0)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}n!m!\sum_{k=0}^{\operatorname{min}(n,m)}\frac{2^k(n+m-2k)!}{k!(n-k)!(m-k)!\left(\frac{n+m}{2}-k\right)!}\left(\frac{1-a}{a}\right)^{\frac{n+m}{2}-k}
$$

This is actually the $b=0$ limit of the question [Integration involving Hermite Polynomials through generating functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460866/integration-involving-hermite-polynomials-through-generating-functions/4203915#4203915).  To see this, the parity has to be even $p=0$ and $b^{2a}$ is only $1$ when $a=0$, in which case this integral reduces to this one.

Comment: @svyatoslav this yielded to my approach.  I'd hate to take a derivative of this though!