# Hermite polynomials (Integral)

Tags: definite-integrals, hermite-polynomials

Could you please help me? How to evaluate this integral
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }x e^{-x^2}H_{2n-1}(xy)dx$$
I tried to use a recurring formula like:
$$H_{2n-1}(xy)=2xyH_{2n-2}(xy)-2(2n-2)H_{2n-3}(xy)$$
So I was able to rewrite the integral as:
$$I_n=y\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }2x^2e^{-x^2}H_{2n-2}(xy)-2(2n-2)I_{n-1}$$
After that I wanted to get the recurrent formula for $I_n$ using integration by parts, but have some troubles with $erf$ function.
I think, that the solution should be easier

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What attempts have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to show your work and review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on providing context in your question to better assist the community.

Comment: it is hard to help you if you don't tell us what is $H_{2n-1}(xy)$

Comment: @DavideTrono $H_{2n-1}(xy)$ - is Hermite polynomial

Comment: Try converting everything into a sum with different indexes so that sum multiplication can be avoided. Keep doing this until you can rearrange and integrate even if the integral is non elementary. Maybe this works or this doesn’t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression can be presented in closed form.
$$ H_{k}(t)=(-1)^ke^{t^2}\frac{d^k}{dt^k}e^{-t^2}$$ $$\frac{d^k}{dt^k}e^{-t^2}=\frac{d^k}{dt^k}\Bigl(\sqrt\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dq}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{q^2}{4}+iqt}\Bigr)=\sqrt\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dq}{2\pi}(iq)^{k}e^{-\frac{q^2}{4}+iqt}$$
$$I(y)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }x e^{-x^2}H_{2n-1}(xy)dx=\frac{1}{y^2}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }dt\, t e^{-\frac{t^2}{y^2}}e^{t^2}(-1)^{2n-1}\frac{d^{2n-1}}{dt^{2n-1}}e^{-t^2}$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt\pi}{2\pi i y^2}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }dt\,dq \,t\,e^{-\frac{1-y^2}{y^2}t^2+iqt}q^{2n-1}e^{-\frac{q^2}{4}}$$
Making full square in the power of the exponent (change $p=t-\frac{iq}{2}\frac{y^2}{1-y^2})$
$$=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt\pi}{2\pi i y^2}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }dp\,dq \,\Bigl(p+\frac{iq}{2}\frac{y^2}{1-y^2}\Bigr)e^{-\frac{1-y^2}{y^2}p^2}q^{2n-1}e^{-\frac{q^2}{4(1-y^2)}}$$
Integral with $p$ in the parentheses wanish (because of the parity of the function). We are left with
$$I(y)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4  (1-y^2)}\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{1-y^2}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }dq\,q^{2n}e^{-\frac{q^2}{4(1-y^2)}}$$
Integral $\,\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }dq\,q^{2n}e^{-\frac{q^2}{4(1-y^2)}}=(-1)^n\frac{d^{n}}{da^{n}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\,$ at $\,a=\frac{1}{4(1-y^2)}$

Could you check and finish from here?

PS the final result is $I(y)=(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt\pi\, 2^{n-1}(2n-1)!!\,y\,(1-y^2)^{n-1}$

Comment: @Tom Davis usage of FT is one of the regular way to solve the problems like this. You motivated me to finish my calculations - the answer $I(y)=(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt\pi (1-y^2)^{n-1}y2^{n-1}(2n-1)!!$ - you can check whether it coincides with yours. I also checked for $n=1\,\, I(1)=\sqrt\pi y$ and for $n=2\,\, I(2)=-6\sqrt\pi y(1-y^2)$. So, I'm afraid the answer is correct.

Comment: Apologies, our answers agree.  Quite different approaches!

Comment: @Tom Davis Yes, the answers are the same, though approached are different :)

Comment: Svyatoslav, if you edit your answer, I can undo my down vote.  Currently it is locked until an edit occurs.  @Svyatoslav

Comment: @Tom Davis, done. Thank you.

Comment: have you seen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592624/integrals-involving-hermite-polynomials  ?

Comment: @Svyatoslav in the answer you wrote $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }dp\,dq \,\Bigl(p+\frac{iq}{2}\frac{y^2}{1-y^2}\Bigr)e^{-\frac{1-y^2}{y^2}p^2}q^{2n-1}e^{-\frac{q^2}{4(1-y^2)}}$, with the differentials in front of the integrand. I've heard on this site that this notation is used to emphasise the *operator* nature of the integral sign, and I'm wondering if that is the case, why is it not written as something like $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }dp\,\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }dq \, \cdots$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer relies on the "Hermite multiplication theorem" (which can be found on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials))
$$
H_n(xy) = \sum_{m=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor}y^{n-2m}(y^2-1)^m {n \choose 2m}\frac{(2m)!}{m!}H_{n-2m}(x).
$$

I will change your integral a bit
$$
I_N = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xH_N(xy)\exp(-x^2)dx.
$$
Expanding (using the Hermite multiplication theorem and the fact that $x=\frac{1}{2}H_1(x)$)
$$
I_N=\sum_{m=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{N}{2} \right \rfloor}y^{N-2m}(y^2-1)^m {N \choose 2m}\frac{(2m)!}{m!}\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_1(x)H_{N-2m}(x)\exp(-x^2)dx.
$$
Now we can use orthogonality
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_a(x)H_b(x)\exp(-x^2)dx =2^a\sqrt{\pi}a!\delta_{a,b}
$$
to enforce $N-2m=1$, or in other words $m=\frac{N-1}{2}$.  Since $m$ is an integer, this implies $N$ must be odd (which is enforced by your notation $N=2n-1$).  Thus,
$$
I_N=\begin{cases} 0 & N \textrm{ even} \\ \sqrt{\pi}\frac{N!}{\left(\frac{N-1}{2}\right)!}y(y^2-1)^{\frac{N-1}{2}} & N \textrm{ odd} \end{cases}.
$$
Therefore, your integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty xH_{2n-1}(xy)\exp(-x^2)dx = \sqrt{\pi}\frac{(2n-1)!}{\left(n-1\right)!}y(y^2-1)^{n-1}.
$$
You could expand this with the binomial theorem for a series in $y$ but I think this form is the most elegant.

This agrees with @svyatoslav's answer above.  To see this, note $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{n-1}$ and therefore the negative sign can be taken into the $(1-y^2)^{n-1}$ term and for odd numbers, the double factorial is precisely equal to
$$
(2n-1)!! = \frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}
$$
see, for example, the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Answer (score 0):

1. This source was used: [Functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/HermiteH/06/01/02/01/)
2. Evaluate:
   $$I=\int_{\Bbb R}xe^{-x^2}H_{2n-1}(xy)dx=
       2\int_0^∞xe^{-x^2}\biggl((2n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n-\frac
       12}\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k(2xy)^{2n-2k-1}}{k!(2n-2k-1)!}\biggr)dx$$
3. $$2\int_0^∞xe^{-x^2}\biggl((2n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n-\frac 12}\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k(2y)^{2n-2k-1}}{k!(2n-2k-1)!}\biggr)dx= 2(2n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n-\frac 12}\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k(2y)^{2n-2k-1}}{k!(2n-2k-1)!} \int_0^∞e^{-x^2}x ^{2n-2k-2}dx$$
4. Logically this integrand looks like the one of the gamma functions. If we expand the $x^{2n-2k-2}$ part, then:
5. $$\int_0^ ∞ e^{-x^2} {(x^2)}^{n-k-\frac 12}x dx=^{u=x^2}\int_0^ ∞ e^{-u} u^{n-k-\frac 12}du=Γ\biggl(n-k+\frac 12 \biggr)$$
6. Therefore our possible final answer is: $$I=2(2n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n-\frac 12}\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k(2y)^{2n-2k-1}}{k!(2n-2k-1)!} Γ\biggl(n-k+\frac 12 \biggr),Re(k-n)<\frac 12 $$
7. Proof of integral:[Proof](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+exp%28-u%29*u%5E%28n-k-1%2F2%29+from+0+to+infinity)

Much easier integral using same method and substitution of summation bounds:$$\int_0^ ∞ xH_n(x) e^{-x^2} dx=\frac{\sqrt π 2^{n-2}}{Γ\biggl(\frac{3-n}{2}\biggr)}$$

Try it out and you will see it is intriguing.

As always this answer may not be correct, so please leave me feedback!I am not sure if the integral can be split apart into 0 to infinity

Or you could always just use the definition of the integral to get a series right away with a limit.

Comment: It seems to me that the main problem is that we cannot take $x^{2n-2k-1}$ out of the sum sign